# How to create a tree list from a list

Tags: linq, c#-4.0

I am stuck in converting a normal list to tree type list. I have to convert like below format:
Can we create a list of parent child relationship?

```
State
 County
   Name
   Name2
 County
   Name3
   Name4
```

And below is my list :

```
{
    "data": [  
        {
            "name": "D1",
            "stateName": "Georgia",
            "stateId": 1,
            "countyName": "Apache",
            "countyId": 1
        },
        {
            "name": "D2",
            "stateName": "Georgia",
            "stateId": 1,
            "countyName": "Apache",
            "countyId": 1
        },
        {
            "name": "D3",
            "stateName": "Georgia",
            "stateId": 1,
            "countyName": "Apache",
            "countyId": 1
        },
        {
            "name": "D4",
            "stateName": "Georgia",
            "stateId": 1,
            "countyName": "Apache",
            "countyId": 1
        },
        {
            "name": "D5",
            "stateName": "Georgia",
            "stateId": 1,
            "countyName": "Catron",
            "countyId": 2
        }   
    ],
    "totalRowCount": 0,
    "errors": []
}
```

Is there any way that I can have tree list. Any help will be appreciated.

I am using below code for tree list but it is not giving me right data.

```
var lstTaxLocation = (from loc in _queryEntities.TaxLocations
                                  join st in _queryEntities.States on loc.StateId equals st.Id
                                  join cou in _queryEntities.Counties on loc.CountyId equals cou.Id
                                  group new { loc, st, cou } by new { st.Id } into pg
                                  let datagroup = pg.FirstOrDefault()
                                  let location = datagroup.loc
                                  let state = datagroup.st
                                  let county = datagroup.cou
                                  select new TaxLocationDto
                                  {
                                      Name = location.Name,
                                      StateId = state.Id,
                                      StateName = state.Name,
                                      CountyName = county.Name,
                                      CountyId = county.Id
                                  });
```

Answer (score 1):

This is very simple to do with LINQ.

Suppose you have your data already deserialized into C# objects:

```
public class Data
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string StateName { get; set; }
    public int StateId { get; set; }
    public string CountyName { get; set; }
    public int CountyId { get; set; }
}
```

You can then use LINQ's [`GroupBy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534304(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`SelectMany`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
var treeList = data.GroupBy(d => d.StateName)
                   .SelectMany(group => group.GroupBy(d => d.CountyName));
```

This will give you the structure you're looking for, but each "node" will be the entire object, not just the `Name` property. You can get that as well if need be, but having the entire object there will most likely help more than just a single property.

Comment: I am not able to use ThenBy method.

Comment: Thanks, that's my bad as I was first getting started on my day. `ThenBy` is only a corollary to `OrderBy`. I've updated my answer to give you what you need.

Comment: It is retrieving data but it is not type cast to Ilist. It is giving me an error of "Unable to cast object of type 'Grouping[my class]' to type my class ''.

Comment: You're right. Remove that, and operate on the groups. You can do a `foreach` on that variable to get the sub groups.